# Построить таблицу умножение вектора

Tags: c++, vector

В векторе vect хранится вектор чисел типа int. Нужно построить таблицу умножения для этих чисел.

В случае с массивом вроде бы понятно, как это можно сделать.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = i, k = n * i; j <= k; j += i) cout << j << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Но как это можно подогнать под вектор?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите что-то [вроде этого](https://ideone.com/dbYAco)?

```
int main() {

    vector<int> x { 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 16 };
    const int N = x.size(), W = 5;

    cout << setw(W) << ' ' << " | ";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) cout << setw(W) << x[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(W) << setfill('-') << '-' << "-+-";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        cout << setw(W + 1) << setfill('-') << "-" ;

    cout << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << setw(W) << x[i] << " | ";

        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cout << setw(W) << x[i]*x[j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
        }
    }
```